# Hydraulic jack mount point on np200/sandero(K7M engine): see pic

Tags: jack, sandero, stands, hydraulic

I'm not sure if this is the correct jack point. I have it under the front bolt on what looks to be a centre frame point between the two front wheels. But there is also one a little further back.

Please confirm the correct hydraulic jack mounting point to position this jack for the purpose of lifting the vehicle onto 2 front jack stands.[image: This picture is taken from the passenger side(RHD)]

This picture is taken from the passenger side(Right-hand drive), behind front-left wheel, under passenger side sill. Looking towards right-hand front side of the vehicle.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is this the Nissan NP200?
The [owners manual](https://www-europe.nissan-cdn.net/content/dam/Nissan/za/OWNERS/OwnerManuals/Nissan%20NP200%20Manual.pdf) shows to jack from the sill -

[image]

However there will be other strong places underneath that will be suitable jacking points.

Where you have the jack doesn’t look suitable to me.  That looks like an engine mounting point, but I may be wrong.

The area around the anti-roll/sway bar mount looks solid -

I would be very careful if you are trying to jack the whole of the front end of the vehicle up at the same time, that would be a lot of weight to put on a single point and also on the jack.

[image]

I’ve just done a Google search for an “NP200 lower engine mount”.  [This is what it looks like](https://www.spareshut.com/products/nissan-nv200-1-5-dci-2010-2018-lower-rear-gearbox-engine-mount-with-bush) -

[image]

This is definitely what you are jacking on -

[image]

You are lifting the weight of the front of the vehicle using the engine, which is not a good idea, you could cause all sorts of damage.  Even the bolt on the other end of the mount doesn’t look substantial enough to use as a jacking point.

Comment: This guy seems to be suggesting it is the safest way.... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=78DWeQwTWvQ&pp=ygUWamFjayBzdGFuZHMgaHlkcmF1bGljIA%3D%3D

Comment: I would need 2 scissor jacks to lift the vehicle up evenly for working underneath... and that would be dangerous. See here https://youtu.be/4shZuy3HR9s?t=318 (he has the vehicle up on two jacks stands.... how did he do that? Surely not with a scissor jack one at a time?)

Comment: Yes... this is the np200. That is the correct owners's manual. Please note I'm not trying to change a wheel, I'm doing a basic service and I need to lift the vehicle high enough to get under the car to drain the oil. I have 2 jack stands I can use but I need to lift the car safely up first from a central point before putting the jacks stands under the sills.

Comment: I am not saying that you can’t lift the whole of the front of the vehicle, but you need to be very careful in finding a good crossmember to do it from.  Also the guy in the video had a jack that looked far more substantial than your jack.

Comment: Ok. The gross weight of the vehicle is 1,890Kg. The hydraulic jack is rated for 2 tons. If the jack is not up to the task then that is a different problem (is a 2 ton jack insufficient? It's really just to hold the wight long enough to get those 2 jack-stands under the sills)

Comment: Just read your comment about the lower engine mount. Okay. So, it's definitely *not* the correct mounting point. Thanks for that.

Comment: So the jack can take the weight, but is it as stable on the ground for lifting the whole front end?  I often jack up each front wheel separately and stand the tyre on a large block of wood.  I feel far more comfortable doing it that way.  I do occasionally lift the whole front end using the front subframe but I have a large jack like the one in the video.  The thoughts of getting under the vehicle to place those axle stands would be scary while supported on a single small jack.  (I guess you could push them into place with a broom, unless they are sat under the sill, are they?)

Comment: Yes, I was going to put them under the sills, but perhaps that is not the best place, so that's again another question. I can't see from the owner's manual you posted a link to where to position a hydraulic jack, or the two jack stands. How can it be this difficult  to find this information? I mean, it's a basic service I'm wanting to do.

Comment: Under the sills should be fine.  Is there not a large strong crossmember that you can see?

Comment: In the photo you look like you have already lifted the vehicle.  Is that the case?

Comment: I modified the picture to resemble what it would look like if I had. Thank goodness I'm not a professional mechanic.

Comment: What were you going to say if I had lifted the vehicle in that spot?

Comment: Nothing, other than if you have already lifted it, you may as well get the job done.  Just find another place to jack it from when taking it off the stands when you are finished.

Comment: I was assuming jacking one side at a time was looking for trouble, but perhaps a stable jack stand is sufficient to do it one side at a time. So perhaps inside control-arm where it joins the frame would be fine.

Comment: Just to update, I decided better safe than sorry... I went with wooden platforms/ramps to achieve the required elevation of the front of the vehicle, to perform the basic service.